# Why do I get this Babel error: unknown option: direct.presets?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, babeljs, create-react-app, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug unit tests in vscode following the instructions from the Facebook page. When I click the debug button in vscode I get this error:

> Fail name-component Test suite failed to run Reference error: Babel
>   spec name : unknown option: direct.presets

How can I debug my unit tests in my cra app in vscode without issues?